# How can i create figures in a foor loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matlab-figure

I have to create a figure for every 80 measurements of a row vector `Bn` with length 31999. I tried to write this code but I receive only one figure with all the measurements (31999):

```
k= length(Bn);
for i= 1:80:(k-1)
    Bn1(i) = L(i);
    plot(Bn1);
end
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector `Bn`, you can extract 80 values starting at index `ii` using `Bn(ii:ii+79)`. Within your loop, you thus need to plot those values only.

However, this will create 400 figure windows, which is unmanageable. I recommend you save the plots to file instead:

```
figure
k = numel(Bn);
for ii = 1:80:k
    plot(Bn(ii:ii+79));
    print('-dpng','-r0',sprintf('plot%.3d',ii))
end
```

The `plot` command will overwrite the previous plot each time.

I recommend you look through the [documentation for `print`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) to learn about the options you have there (different file formats `-d` and resolutions `-r`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create one figure for each element, just insert the `figure` command inside the loop

```
k= length(Bn);
for i= 1:80:(k-1)
    figure % this is what you need
    Bn1(i) = L(i);
    plot(Bn1);
end
```

I'm not sure what `L` is, so I can't tell if that will do what you expect, but that will create a new figure for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: ok now i have a figure for each loop but i'm wrong in something.. i try to be more clear.. i expect to have a figure for all the data of L from 1 to 80 of Bn and increment Bn by 80 an soo on until the maximum length of Bn.. so the next figure will show the data of L from 81 to 161 of Bn.